DBT - Snowflake - Model trying to alter a column
I have an incremental model in dbt that uses the data of a stream (as a source) and tries to merge into a next table.
I'm facing the problem that one of the columns is defined in the 1st table (on which the stream is created) as col_1 VARCHAR(3) and the field in the 2nd table as col_1 VARCHAR(3).
The the select statement in the model that is trying to do the merge onto the 2nd table (table_2) is set as:
SELECT
    CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(col_1, '[^\x00-\x7F]', '') AS VARCHAR(3) ) AS col_1, 
    ...
FROM
    DB.SCHEMA.stream_table_1
WHERE
    METADATA$ACTION = 'INSERT'
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...) = 1

And the DBT execution log is showing:

13:50:01  SQL status: SUCCESS 57 in 0.0 seconds 13:50:01  Changing col
type from character varying(3) to character varying(16777216) in table
database: "DB" schema: "SCHEMA" identifier: "table_2"
13:50:01  Using snowflake connection
"model.workspace.table_2" 13:50:01  On
model.workspace.table_2: /* {"app": "dbt", "dbt_version":
"1.8.0", "profile_name": "but_worspace", "target_name": "qa",
"node_id": "model.workspace.table_2"} */ alter table
db.schema.table_2 alter "col_1" set data type character
varying(16777216); 13:50:02  Snowflake adapter: Snowflake query id:
01b4587e-0105-28c1-003f-f70708b39e12

I don't know what is doing, why is an alter appearing on this?

Hi, could you please share the code of the dbt model?

@KlimentMerzlyakov {{ config(unique_key = 'col_1', 'col_2'], merge_exclude_columns = ['col_1', 'col_2'] ) }}
SELECT col_1, col_2, REGEXP_REPLACE(col_3, '[^\x00-\x7F]', '') AS col_3, col_4,  col_5, REGEXP_REPLACE(col_6, '[^\x00-\x7F]', '') AS col_6, col_7, REGEXP_REPLACE(col_8, '[^\x00-\x7F]', '') AS col_8, REGEXP_REPLACE(col_9, '[^\x00-\x7F]', '') AS col_9, current_timestamp() as SYSTEM_CREATED_TIMESTAMP, NULL as SYSTEM_STORAGE_LOCATION FROM  {{ source('source_','stream_table_1') }} WHERE METADATA$ACTION = 'INSERT'
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col_1, col_2 ORDER BY col_4) = 1

@KlimentMerzlyakov then in a second attempt we add the explicit: CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(col_3, '[^\x00-\x7F]', '') AS VARCHAR(3)) AS col_3

Thank you for sharing!
Did I understand correctly that you have one incremental model that initially did not have CAST in it, and you add CAST later on to the same model?

@KlimentMerzlyakov, yes, the model that we first run doesn't have the CAST on the col_3 column which is the one that is alleging. After we tried to put a CAST on the model that explicitly change to VARCHAR(3), but the same error pop ups

@KlimentMerzlyakov its like dbt its trying to convert a VARCHAR(3) into a VARCHAR(16777216) (i don't know why) and because the role that we are using only have R/W permissions, fails

In your scenario, you have created a model without any casting. Later, you've added CAST functions to the same model.
In this case, your table is already created on the initial run of the model.
Running dbt run --full-refresh should fix the issue.
❗️ Please beware that it will drop your current table completely and recreate it from scratch. Generally (I'd say 99.9% of the time), you should design dbt models so you can run --full-refresh on them.
There is might be a misconception on what incremental models are for.
Incremental models:
✅ serve to optimize a dbt workload (if dbt run executes too long)
❌ do not serve to extract and load data from a streaming
Please see more details from my answer here.
dbt is responsible for the T component in the ELT (Extract, Load, Transform). It seems that you're trying to use dbt for E and L. I believe it will be highly beneficial for you if you use another tool for extracting and storing data from your streaming to the RAW database of Snowflake. And then, use view or table dbt models to transform this data for business usage.

thanks for the response. Our current model uses oracle cawa orchestrating the extractions from onpremise dbs and load data into snowflake, into a first level raw tables. Each one have a stream on it to make CDC, theres where we take that data from each streams and move it to another tables that also have streams on top. After, a final model on dbt, transform the data (joins, etc) and merge the information in this final tables. Cause all of this tables are transactional and each day new records are inserted or updated, we decided to use incremental models to only insert or update this new data.

Sounds good. Check out my post above through the link. Incremental models provide a level of complexity, so dbt recommends to start from views, if performance is not good enough move to tables. And only if you face performance or “money issue” move to incremental. Don’t use incremental models as an extracting pipeline.
dbt run --full-refresh will solve your issue. Beware it will drop your table. If that’s a concern for you — see my comments above, as you most probably misuse incremental models then.

we tried to use dbt run --full-refresh just now but doesn't work. The thing is that the problem exists before we tried using the CAST( AS VARCHAR(3)). We just understood that the role that we are using on snowflake through dbt only have R/W permissions so when dbt is trying to do the alter table (showed in the error message) fails cause doesn't have the permissions. But we don't understand we is trying to do this alter table alter column thing

Oh, I see, could you probably share the error message?
In your post it says that it's changing col type, but what is the error?
